# Java HashMap Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: android, json, multithreading, sqlite

I am fetching HashMap from JSONArray and sending it to SQLite. Its giving me :
  `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String. HashMap conversion issue.`

The type is HashMap<Integer,HashMap<String,String>>.

```
for(int i=0;i<adsarray.length();i++){
      JSONObject obj=adsarray.getJSONObject(i);
      HashMap mapReceivedAdDetails=new HashMap();
      HashMap mapBusinessInfo=new HashMap();    

      //mapBusinessInfo.put
      mapReceivedAdDetails.put("RecAdId", obj.getInt("received_ad_id"));
      mapReceivedAdDetails.put("RecBusinessId",obj.getInt("business_id"));
      mapReceivedAdDetails.put("RecBusinessId",obj.getInt("user_id"));
      mapReceivedAdDetails.put("RecAdtitle",obj.getString("received_ad_title"));
      mapReceivedAdDetails.put("RecAdDetail",obj.getString("received_ad_detail"));
      mapReceivedAdDetails.put("RecBusinessZip",obj.getString("business_zip"));
      mapReceivedAdDetails.put("RecBusinessCountry", obj.getString("business_country"));
      mapReceivedAdDetails.put("AdCreated", obj.getString("adreceived_created"));
      mapReceivedAd.put(i, mapReceivedAdDetails);

     //Log.i("ReceivedId",mapReceivedAd.toString());

      mapBusinessInfo.put("BusinessId",obj.getInt("business_id"));
      mapBusinessInfo.put("BusUserId",obj.getInt("user_id"));
      mapBusinessInfo.put("BusName",obj.getString("business_name"));
      mapBusinessInfo.put("BusSt1",obj.getString("business_street1"));
      mapBusinessInfo.put("BusSt2",obj.getString("business_street2"));
      mapBusinessInfo.put("BusCity",obj.getString("business_city"));
      mapBusinessInfo.put("BusState",obj.getString("business_state"));
      mapBusinessInfo.put("BusCountry",obj.getString("business_country"));
      mapBusinessInfo.put("BusZip",obj.getString("business_zip"));
      mapBusinessInfo.put("BusContactNo",obj.getString("business_contactno"));
      mapBusinessInfo.put("BusWebsite",obj.getString("business_website"));
      mapBusinessInfo.put("BusCreated",obj.getString("business_created"));
      mapBusinessDetail.put(i,mapBusinessInfo);
    // Log.i("BusinessDetail",mapBusinessDetail.toString());



     /* ad_business_id=obj.getInt("business_id");
      ad_user_id=obj.getInt("user_id");
      receive_ad_title=obj.getString("received_ad_title");
      receive_ad_detail=obj.getString("received_ad_detail");
      ad_business_zip=obj.getString("business_zip");
      ad_business_country=obj.getString("business_country");*/
      //ad_date_created=obj.getString("date_created");
      //Log.i("+ad_business_id+"+"+ad_user_id+" "+receive_ad_title+" "+receive_ad_detail+" "+ad_business_zip+" "+ad_business_country+" ");

 }
```

SQLIte code

```
while(i<mapBusinessInfo.size())
    {

      insert.bindLong(1, Integer.parseInt(mapBusinessInfo.get(i).get("BusUserId")));
      insert.bindLong(2, Integer.parseInt(mapBusinessInfo.get(i).get("BusinessId")));
      insert.bindString(3, mapBusinessInfo.get(i).get("BusName"));
      insert.bindString(4, mapBusinessInfo.get(i).get("BusSt1"));
      insert.bindString(5, mapBusinessInfo.get(i).get("BusSt2"));
      insert.bindString(6, mapBusinessInfo.get(i).get("BusCity"));
      insert.bindString(7, mapBusinessInfo.get(i).get("BusState"));
      insert.bindString(8, mapBusinessInfo.get(i).get("BusCountry"));
      insert.bindString(9, mapBusinessInfo.get(i).get("BusZip"));
      insert.bindString(10, mapBusinessInfo.get(i).get("BusContactNo"));
      insert.bindString(11, mapBusinessInfo.get(i).get("BusWebsite"));
      insert.bindLong(12, Long.parseLong(mapBusinessInfo.get(i).get("BusCreated")));
      insert.execute();
      i++;

    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    Log.i("Transaction", "Successful");
}
```

Error at:

```
insert.bindLong(1, Integer.parseInt(mapBusinessInfo.get(i).get("BusUserId")));
```

Below is Logcat:

> 03-13 09:05:23.034 18810-18866/? W/System.err:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String 03-13 09:05:23.034 18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.SQLITEDatabase.DatabaseHandle.InserBusinessInfo(DatabaseHandle.java:143)
>   03-13 09:05:23.042 18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.deals.NewUserDetailPage$fetchadvertisements.doInBackground(NewUserDetailPage.java:283)
>   03-13 09:05:23.042 18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.deals.NewUserDetailPage$fetchadvertisements.doInBackground(NewUserDetailPage.java:255)
>   03-13 09:05:23.046 18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 03-13 09:05:23.062
>   18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   03-13 09:05:23.062 18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 03-13
>   09:05:23.066 18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 03-13
>   09:05:23.070 18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   03-13 09:05:23.070 18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   03-13 09:05:23.086 18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 03-13 09:05:23.138 18810-18866/?
>   W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside
>   thread that has not called Looper.prepare() 03-13 09:05:23.170
>   18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:121) 03-13 09:05:23.170
>   18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.widget.Toast$TN.(Toast.java:322) 03-13 09:05:23.174
>   18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:91) 03-13 09:05:23.186
>   18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238) 03-13 09:05:23.186
>   18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.deals.NewUserDetailPage$fetchadvertisements.doInBackground(NewUserDetailPage.java:285)
>   03-13 09:05:23.194 18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   com.example.deals.NewUserDetailPage$fetchadvertisements.doInBackground(NewUserDetailPage.java:255)
>   03-13 09:05:23.206 18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 03-13 09:05:23.214
>   18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>   03-13 09:05:23.218 18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 03-13
>   09:05:23.222 18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 03-13
>   09:05:23.254 18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>   03-13 09:05:23.274 18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>   03-13 09:05:23.282 18810-18866/? W/System.err:     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 03-13 09:05:23.454 320-320/?
>   W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus
>   gain of:
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@535c3eec
>   attribute=null

Comment: Where is the error happening in your code?  Post the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

You can freely convert `Hashmap` into `String` there will be no offense at all. But what you are doing is you have Hasmap called `mapReceivedAdDetails` and you are trying to convert another variable which was not shown in snippet `mapReceivedAd`.

**So instead of doing**

```
mapReceivedAd.toString();
```

**Do**

```
mapReceivedAdDetails.toString();
```

Comment: Hi Sree krishna, Thank you for looking into it. I am doing HashMap.toString(); just to see what values are stored. My challenge is below, converting it. I am first fetching it from Int to storing in String HashMap and then converting it back to int while inserting into SQLite,
insert.bindLong(1, Integer.parseInt(mapBusinessInfo.get(i).get("BusUserId")));
      insert.bindLong(2, Integer.parseInt(mapBusinessInfo.get(i).get("BusinessId")));

Comment: Use `String.valueOf(integer)` to convert `integer` back to `String`. You may have doing something else.

Comment: It's working now. In fetching the value from the JSONArray. Changed it to obj.get("business_Id") instead of obj.getInt("business_id"). So get instead of getInt.